# When is "Dammit to hell" used?

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

When would native speakers utter "dammit to hell"?

Would it be natural to use if you hurt yourself in some way?

(This is a serious question)

Comment: Swear words and phrases are very personal. I don't think I would ever use that phrase. Others would use it in wide circumstances.

Comment: You say this is a serious question.  Perhaps you could clarify:  Have you found yourself in this situation and needed an expression to use?  Do you expect to be in this situation? Have other speakers used this expression in your presence? Are you writing a story and you want a character to sound natural.  Please explain why this is a serious question.

Comment: Never. I think it is always "dammit it all to hell!"

Answer (score 4):

It would be in a moment of stress, frustration and anger.

In pain "ouch" or some non-verbal sound "aghhouuee"

But if your computer monitor isn't working so you try to use your phone to check your emails but then you find that you need a mobile log-in code due to a new "security policy" that can only be provided by head office. But head office is closed for the Thai New Year and so the bonus you were hoping to get by closing the contract early is going to be lost then  "Dammit all to hell! Damm monitor, Damn stupid security policy, Damn head office. Damn them all to hell and back!"

There isn't a particular situation in which this is natural.  It might be part of an individual's language, but it isn't a regular or idiomatic expression.

For language learners:  Don't bother.  You will not sound more "natural" if you swear unnaturally.  It is not required. Many native speakers swear a lot.  Many very rarely swear. You don't need to "learn to swear".  It will come naturally if you need it.  If it doesn't come naturally, that is because you don't need it and you shouldn't be swearing.